# Why does Sort fail in this simple example?

Tags: sorting

I'm sure I'll be embarrassed by the answer, but I don't understand why I get the following result:

```
list = {{9, "b"}, {4, "a"}, {7, "k4"}, {6, "k3"}, {5, "w"}}
```

This works:

```
Sort[list]  
(* {{4, "a"}, {5, "w"}, {6, "k3"}, {7, "k4"}, {9, "b"}}*)
```

This works:

```
Sort[list, #1[[1]] > #2[[1]] &]   
(*{{9, "b"}, {7, "k4"}, {6, "k3"}, {5, "w"}, {4, "a"}}  *)
```

But this fails:

```
Sort[list, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &]   
(*{{9, "b"}, {4, "a"}, {7, "k4"}, {6, "k3"}, {5, "w"}}*)
```

**Question:**

Why would it work using `SortBy[]` and not `Sort[]`?

Comment: `SortBy[list, #[[2]] &]`?

Comment: @Öskå SortBy[] does work, but I think Sort[] should work too.

Comment: The `Less` operator (`<`) remains unevaluated on strings, thus your last result.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I saw that the problem occurs only with strings, but I didn't know why. Is SortBy[] the only approach, or is there another that allows Sort[] to work (or is this issue unimportant)?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Should this be considered a flaw in Sort[]?

Comment: The answer posted by @xzczd addresses your question regarding `Sort`. The reason it does not work with strings is that `Less` is not defined for strings, and you have to use a different comparison operator/function (like in mentioned answer).

Comment: No, it is not a flaw in `Sort`. You have to use a correct comparison function, which you did not, for strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Leonid Shifrin has pointed out why the 3rd sample fails: `Less` doesn't "compare" strings.

Still, it's possible to use `Sort`, with the addition of `OrderedQ`:

```
Sort[list, OrderedQ[{#1[[2]], #2[[2]]}] &]
```

> {{4, "a"}, {9, "b"}, {6, "k3"}, {7, "k4"}, {5, "w"}}

Answer (score 4):

Another sort of short `Sort` is

```
#/@Sort[#/@list]&@Reverse

(* ==> {{4, "a"}, {9, "b"}, {6, "k3"}, {7, "k4"}, {5, "w"}} *)
```

This puts the strings in first position before sorting, and then puts the strings back in second place afterwards.

Comment: This sort of short sort seems surprisingly simple

Comment: +1. Another obscure way to do this, avoiding `Map`: `Composition[#, Sort, #] &[Reverse[#, {2}] &][list]`

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Ah, a last-resort re-sort. I think you can just use `Reverse[#, 2]` for this list.